# Why is $(\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2)/\text{s}$ written as "Joule second" when there is no joule present, and time is divided and not multiplied?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, units, si-units

The Joule is $(\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2)/\text{s}^2$, which is not contained in $(\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2)/\text{s}$, the Joule second. So, why does the unit name contain "Joule"?

Also, "Joule second" or "J s" seems to imply "Joule multiplied by second," yet in $(\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2)/\text{s}$, the second is not multiplied by anything.

...

Edit: @JEB's answer touched on the question I did not explicitly ask, but should have:

"Why is the Joule-second a unit, when (kg⋅m2)/s could have its own unit name? Why include the 'second' in the unit name?"

Comment: To the downvoters - constructive criticism will help me improve my questions

Comment: It was probably getting downvotes because it seems like an almost trivial question that could be answered by just looking at the definition of a Joule. Also it was originally posted without using MathJax/Latex so the equations looked pretty ugly, which can annoy people. Get yourself a basic physics textbook like Halliday and Resnick and a lot of these simple questions will be answered in there--you can probably find an older edition free somewhere on the great big Internet.

Comment: @hft - thank you for feedback! I've seen a debate on other "too trivial" to warrant answers" posts, but experienced posters with thousands of reputation have said that basic questions can be useful. I did not fully understand the MathJax, but I've found and read over this - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Thank you for pointing me to a good basic Physics text. I think I worded the question wrong - I should have said "Why Joule-second as unit instead of giving (kg⋅m2)/s its own unit name? Why include the 'second' in the unit?"

Comment: @hft On including words in units that seem superfluous - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548212/why-do-kilowatt-hours-double-count-units-per-time/548224#548224

Comment: @hft I am confused - I see in your answer below that you used the exact same formatting I originally used for the equations in my question, "∗2/2" - why did you say it looked ugly? For example, when you said I needed to use MathJax, I found the link I just posted and found that multiplication is to use "×" or the "⋅", but you used niether - you used the "*" just as I did.

Comment: I used the same format you originally used. I thought it would be easier for you to understand, not because it looks good.

Comment: @hft - You violated your own standards of clarity and aesthetics in order to answer a question you didn't think was worth asking?

Comment: hey guy, nobody cares.

Comment: @hft - I'm very confused at this point. I genuinely want to learn how to improve my questions on SE, thus I sincerely want to understand your feedback. But your posts are beginning to make me wonder if your goals are different from my own. Overall, I have gleaned from your feedback, and I appreciate you and your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[One Joule is defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) $$1 \text{ J} = 1 \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2}{\text{s}^2}.$$ Hence,
$$1 \text{ J} \cdot \text{s} = 1 \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2}{\text{s}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Try multiplying top and bottom by seconds.

Comment: If I multiply the top and the bottom by seconds, the seconds cancel out, and I'm left with the unit with which I began. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is  (kg⋅m2)/s  written as "Joule second" when there is no joule present, and time is divided and not multiplied?

A Joule is a unit of energy. Units of energy can also be written as units of $kg*m^2/s^2$.

$kg*m^2/s = s * (kg*m^2/s^2) = s * Joule;,$ i.e., "Joule-seconds."

Answer (score 0):

The Joule-second is important because it is the unit of $\hbar$.

As far as the Joule is concerned, we know work is force ($F=ma$) times distance, so energy has units:

$${\rm kg\cdot m/s^2\times m = kg\frac{m^2}{s^2}=kg
\Big(\frac{m}{s}\Big)^2}$$

which agrees with kinetic energy being $\frac 1 2 m v^2$.

Perhaps $\hbar$'s  most famous role is relating frequency and energy:

$$ E = \hbar\omega $$

or

$$ \hbar = \frac E {\omega}$$

So that unit is Joules per Hertz (J/Hz), which is a more natural way to view the relation than Joules times seconds, though they are equivalent.

Comment: I didn't realize the Joule-second was equivalent to another unit, though I did wonder why (kg⋅m2)/s did not have its own unit name. Now I know that it does have its own unit name!

Comment: @JBR it is best know as the units of *Action* in physics, like in the Principle of stationary (least) action.